# How to instantiate stdClass in place

Tags: php, javascript, code-snippets, stdclass

Is it it possible to do this in php?

Javascript code:

```
var a = {name: "john", age: 13}; //a.name = "john"; a.age = 13
```

Instantiate the stdClass variable on the fly ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the associative array syntax, and casting to `object`:

```
$a = (object)array('name' => 'john', 'age' => 13);
echo $a->name; // 'john'
```

Comment: Casting seems the best method, but i think you cast it to (object) rather than (stdClass) as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @adam: right you are. Did `stdClass` use to work or something? I have it in my head that it did work once upon a time.

Comment: I think php always reports objects as stdClass (with var_dump, etc) but the actual type is object. Should be the same in both directions, if you ask me.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->name = 'john';
$a->age = 13;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
$text = '{"name": "john", "age": 13}';
$obj = json_decode($text);
```

Comment: Requires much more processing than casting an array to an object.